# How can I configure visibility rules for mini-panel panes based on url alias?

Tags: panels

I'm using panels everywhere (I'm new to this) and thought it would be a good idea to create a mini-panel for my header and include that in my panels-based site layout. I want to switch the main menu in this header based on the url structure (mydomain.com/dogs would have a different menu than mydomain.com/cats).

I thought it made sense to create different menus for each scenario and configure their visibility settings based on that url structure. However, when I try to configure visibility settings for any content added to a pane within my header mini-panel based on "String: URL path", nothing happens and it's hidden for every page.

I should mention that the Path dropdown in the visibility settings only has the option of 'No context'. Should this have an 'aliased url' option? When I enter say, 'node/28' the visibility filter works correctly, but not for the aliased url.

I should also mention that we're running this site on IIS, but have done this many times with Drupal.

What am I missing here?